# Update a Semantic Model in Fabric after adding columns to one of the tables in my Lakehouse

Tags: database, powerbi

I have a fabric workspace with a Lakehouse. Based on the Lakehouse i build a semantic model (to create the right relations and to create schedueled updates). Based on the semantic model i build a Power BI report. Now i added a new column in one of my tables in the Lakehouse.

I want to know if i can update my semantic model so it includes the new column or do i have to start over and make a new model and then a new power bi report?

I tried to find a place to update the semantic model, but did not succed in adding the new column from my lakehouse.